# Easily build a Mac OS X .app bundled with MacPorts

Tags: xcode, macos, go, package, otool

There is a [bash script](https://github.com/agl/pond/blob/master/client/build-osx-bundle.sh) to build a Mac OS X .app bundle from an application written in Go that works by extracting the necessary libraries, resources, etc. from a Homebrew installation and tweaking the libraries.  I'm happy adding MacPorts support, but..

Aren't there easier ways to do this, like using Xcode projects or whatever?  Is there an analog of [py2app](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) for go?  What should I know about using outside libraries in .app bundles?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you properly, you want to pack a Go binary as a OS X `.app` file. Well, yes, you can do it. Take a look on `Makefile` of my [cocoa-go](https://github.com/kavu/cocoa-go) project. In fact, building `.app` if fairly easy. Also, I can recommend a Developer Library article about bundles — [Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Should the article be linked somehow (as it is not the case at the moment)?

Comment: It's way more complicated than your cocoa-go example.  In particular, it requires tweaking libraries and non-library resources form macports.